# What's the proper way to define response model for synchronization purpose when using microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

I'm using a microservice architecture. when something went in one microservice I want to catch it in another microservice. To say briefly I have synchronization. But there I have one problem, I have a domain model with its own attributes and behavior, I would like to get that data in another microservice. Basically I'm just sending a request from one Microservice to another and I'm pulling some data, but to get this data I need to have the same model in both microservice.

I got two possible choices:

1. To have two model one for Domain model and another for response a.k.a "DTO". (Disadvantage: If I update something in the domain model I should update it in the DTO model.)
2. To have a lot of atomic models for specific tasks. (Disadvantage: hard to maintain all of the models)

I'm looking for best practices for this specific decision.

Comment: how are you communicating between your microservices?

Comment: The best practice is not sharing any model at all. Just share events, changes, operations. Let each MS stay aware of these things and do with them whatever they need with their respective models. Otherwise, you are not synchronizing, you are replicating

Comment: I'm using a service bus for communication. I need to get specific data from one microservice to another to finish the process.

Comment: No good news for you. It might [interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900551/why-esb-is-considered-bad-in-microservices-architecture). You can find more references if you look for Microservices vs ESB.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, this same problem exists in every architecture, not just microservices. If the contract for something you rely on changes then you need to change also. Are you asking how to deal with/minimize those changes? If so there may be a better way to phrase it is all I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at an individual service visualise it as "this is the only thing in the world". Note down its inputs and outputs. The outputs go via its API's. Its inputs can come from either its API and/or its message bus. Having two services that depend on each others schema's is an anti-pattern and degrades the benefits you're supposed to be leveraging.

If you need data to go between services, use the message bus; but send the data via events. "This happened" with "this data". Each service can interpret that however it wants and do whatever it wants with it.